# inverted pyramid in java

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

how to create a pyramid like this with loop

```
******   6 asterisks

 ****    4 asterisks

  **      2 asterisks

  *      1 asterisk
```

My try:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     for(int k=0; k<=i; k++){
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for(int j=0; j<6-(2*i); j++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     } 
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This hurts my eyes. Please format your code before posting!

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: I don't get the last asterisk

Comment: It's because you're subtracting 2 from the number if asterisks to draw each time, but the last line is a special case since it should go from 2 to 1, not 2 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i : new Integer[]{6,4,2,1}){
     for(int k = 0; k < (6 - i)/2; k++){
         System.out.print(" ");
     }           
     for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     } 
     System.out.println();
}
```

Or alternatively this works also with bigger pyramids

```
int MAX = 6;    
int i = MAX;
while(i > 0){
     for(int k = 0; k < (MAX - i)/2; k++){
         System.out.print(" ");
     }           
     for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     } 
     System.out.println();

     i = i * 2 / 3;
}
```